# How can I fill in simple forms using bookmarklets? Trouble shooting my simple code

Tags: javascript, html, autofill, bookmarklet

Good afternoon,

To save time at work, I am trying to use js autofill scripts. Bookmarklets seems to be the best way of doing this but the simple code I have doesn't seem to work.

As a test page, I have been trying-  http://gangstaname.com/names/gangsta#.Ymf-cujMJPa
as it's a simple site with just one form with an id.

I've created a bookmark and changed the code to

```
javascript:document.getElementById("NameGangstaForm").value = "Mark";
```

In theory from what I've read, upon clicking this it should change the field value from blank to 'Mark' but instead it blanks the whole page and inserts the new name in the top left corner.

Apologies for the page and my apparent lack of knowledge but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#NameGangstaForm` is `<form>` you want to select `<input>` with element ID `#NameName`

```
javascript:document.querySelector("#NameName").value = "Mark";void(0);
```

it better to use `querySelector()` instead of `getElementById()` because in the future you can easy switch to jQuery or CSS

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Unfortunately it still just blanks the screen and displays the name Mark in the top left corner. Should this work in a regular chrome browser with no settings changed? I've had a look and Javascript is enabled so it's left me scratching my head.

Comment: add `void(0)` at the end of script, see above

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks a lot for your help. I'll have a look into that and see where I may need it next. Thanks again

Comment: you're welcome, dont forget to mark the answer as correct